# Problems with less mix-ins

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to do (I think) a really simple mixin in LESS, and I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

I'm compiling with Visual Studio Web Essentials.

So here's my goal:
I want a style that is just like the boostrap control-label, except I want to change some property (let's say padding):

Here's my LESS:

```
@import (reference) 'bootstrap/bootstrap.less';
    .my-test-class {
      .control-label;
      padding: 4;
    }
```

This results in a compile error:
NameError: .control-label is undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `.control-label()` for a mixin. See http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature

Comment: @megawac: See the end of that link; the parentheses are optional.

Comment: it doesn't seem to matter whether I use the parens -- same error.  I am referencing the boostrap.less file.  Is there another import that I need to use?  For that matter, does LESS permit what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, all the `.control-label` class definitions reside within other class definitions [in this file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/forms.less). Specifically, inside either `.form-inline` and `.form-horizontal`. However within `.form-inline` it is also inside a media query, which at present prevents it from being accessed as a mixin.

So that means you must access it via the only namespace available, like so:

```
@import (reference) 'bootstrap/bootstrap.less';

.my-test-class {
  .form-horizontal > .control-label;
  padding: 4;
}
```

The general principle to learn from this is one really needs to be aware of what the bootstrap code actually outputs to be able to access (or know whether you *can* even access) a piece of it as a mixin (whether importing it as `(reference)` or not).